# Get MAX value from Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012

I want to get the `MAX` value of `SalesMade` and display the corresponding `Employee.FirstName` and `Employee.LastName`. This query returns the count of the sales made by each employee. Can you help me calculate the MAX value? I am not familiar with subqueries. Thanks in advance.

```
SELECT Employees.FirstName, Employees.LastName, COUNT(Sales.EmployeeID) AS SalesMade, DATEPART(month, Sales.Date) AS Month, DATEPART(year, Sales.Date) AS Year
FROM Employees INNER JOIN Sales ON Employees.EmployeeId = Sales.EmployeeID
GROUP BY Employees.FirstName, Employees.LastName, Sales.Date
ORDER BY SalesMade
```

Comment: What kind of help do you need?

Comment: *"This query returns the count of the sales made by each employee."* Actually, it returns the number of sales made by each employee **on each day**. Do you want a query that returns the largest total sales per employee (altogether), the largest sales by a single employee each day, or the largest sales by a single employee on any day ever?

Comment: 'This query returns the count of the sales made by each employee. Can you help me calculate the MAX value?'. I need the Max value from the SalesMade Column. I tried a few subqueries but they dont work

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a subquery.  Assuming that you really mean total sales and not sales per day:

```
SELECT top 1 e.FirstName, e.LastName, COUNT(*) AS SalesMade
FROM Employees e INNER JOIN
     Sales s
     ON e.EmployeeId = s.EmployeeID
GROUP BY e.EmployeeId, e.FirstName, e.LastName
ORDER BY SalesMade desc;
```

The `top 1` returns only the first row, which would be the maximum because of the `order by` clause.

Answer (score 0):

I main question is what is the business logic?

Are you trying to get the name of the employee who sold the most per day, month or year?

Also, are you looking for total number of sales or the maximum amount sold?

These could all be valid queries.

I like creating a couple test tables and load them into tempdb for playing (sales/employees) with sample primary and foreign keys.

Since the HOBBIT is in the movies, I gave Bilbo 2 sales on 12/24 and 1 sale on 12/26.  On the other hand, Gandalf had 1 sale on 12/24 and 3 sales on 12/26

```
-- Just playing around
use tempdb;
go

-- employee table
if object_id('employees') > 0 
drop table employees
go

create table employees
(
   employee_id int identity(1,1) primary key,
   first_name varchar(25),
   last_name varchar(25)
);
go

-- add data
insert into employees values
('bilbo', 'baggins'),
('gandalf', 'the grey');
go

-- show data
select * from employees
go

-- sales table
if object_id('sales') > 0 
drop table sales
go

create table sales
(
   sales_id int identity(1,1) primary key,
   employee_id int,
   sales_date datetime,
   sales_amount money
);

-- add data
insert into sales values
(1, '12/24/2013', 100),
(1, '12/24/2013', 200),
(2, '12/24/2013', 300),
(2, '12/26/2013', 100),
(2, '12/26/2013', 200),
(2, '12/26/2013', 300),
(1, '12/24/2013', 100);
go

-- make sure their is integrity
alter table sales add constraint [fk_employee_id] 
foreign key (employee_id) references employees (employee_id);

-- show data
select * from sales
go
```

This simple query returns total sales per day per employee.

```
-- Total Sales per Day per employee
SELECT 
    s.sales_date, 
    e.last_name, 
    e.first_name, 
    COUNT(*) AS total_sales
FROM employees e INNER JOIN sales s
ON e.employee_id = s.employee_id
GROUP BY 
    s.sales_date,
    e.last_name, 
    e.first_name
```

[image]

I noticed you added DATEPART for month and year at the end?  Are you trying to get the sales per month?

```
-- Total Sales per Month per employee
SELECT 
    datepart(yyyy, s.sales_date) * 100 + datepart(mm, s.sales_date) as date_key, 
    e.last_name, 
    e.first_name, 
    COUNT(*) AS total_sales
FROM employees e INNER JOIN sales s
ON e.employee_id = s.employee_id
GROUP BY 
    datepart(yyyy, s.sales_date) * 100 + datepart(mm, s.sales_date), 
    e.last_name, 
    e.first_name
ORDER BY total_sales desc;
```

[image]

In short, the **top 1** will only help if you are looking at a particular day or month.  If you want to see the top sales person per day or month over a range of days or months, **it will not work**.

Please clarify the business logic so that I can give you an exact solution.